# All of spritesheet being displayed onto screen

Tags: python, pygame

I have a problem with my game which isn't a bug but a problem. I am using spritesheets to make my game and using a for loop to call my Platform class automaticaly. However when I try to call the the platform class it just displays the whole spritesheet. There may be an error in the class platform or level_1 but I am not sure what it is. Please can you help me if you have pygame.
[An image of what is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i94lM.png)

```
import pygame
# Colours + Global constants
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0,  0, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RANDOM = (12, 211, 123)
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600
SIZE = (WIDTH, HEIGHT)


# CLASSES
# Block is the common platform
```

Platform class:

```
class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, display, x_screen, y_screen, x_sheet, y_sheet, height, length):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.image.load("tiles_spritesheet.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        display.blit(self.image, (x_screen, y_screen), (x_sheet, y_sheet, height, length))
```

Level_1 class:

```
class Level01(Level):
    def __init__(self, player1, monster, display):
        # Initialise level1
        super().__init__()
        # Level01 things
        block = Block(WIDTH*3, 3, BLACK)
        Level.all_things = self.all_things

        self.sprites.add(player1, monster)
        self.platforms.add(block)
        self.all_things.add(player1, block, monster)

        theLevel = [[1, HEIGHT, 0, 0],
                    [1, HEIGHT, WIDTH*3, 0]]

        level = [[600, 400, 710, 0, 70, 70]]

        for platform in theLevel:
            block = Block(platform[0], platform[1], RED)
            block.rect.x = platform[2]
            block.rect.y = platform[3]
            self.platforms.add(block)
            self.all_things.add(block)

        for goodPlatform in level:
            platform = Platform(display, goodPlatform[0], goodPlatform[1], goodPlatform[2], goodPlatform[3], goodPlatform[4], goodPlatform[5])
            self.platforms.add(platform)
            self.all_things.add(platform)
```

main:

```
def main():
    # Init pygame
    pygame.init()
    # Set screen
    background = pygame.image.load("background.jpg")
    backgroundRect = background.get_rect()
    display = pygame.display.set_mode(background.get_size())
    # Creating FPS thingy
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    # Making levels  + Player
    monster = Monster(30, 30, RANDOM)
    player = Player()
    level_1 = Level01(player, monster, display)
    # Choosing level
    levelList = []
    levelList.append(level_1)
    currentLevelNumber = 0
    currentLevel = levelList[currentLevelNumber]
    y_speed = -5
    # Game loop
    loop = True
    while loop == True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        player.move_right()
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        player.move_left()
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        player.move_up(currentLevel.platforms)
                    if event.key == pygame.KMOD_LSHIFT and event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        player.sprint()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and player.sprite_x_change < 0:
                    player.stop()
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and player.sprite_x_change > 0:
                    player.stop()
                if event.key == pygame.KMOD_LSHIFT:
                    player.sprite_x_change -= 10
        # Update things
        #monster.jump()
        if player.rect.x > 400:
            player.rect.x = 400
            currentLevel.scroll_x(-10)

        if player.rect.x >= WIDTH:
            player.rect.x = WIDTH
            currentLevel.scroll(0)

        if player.rect.y >= HEIGHT:
            main()

        if player.sprite_x_change < 0 and player.rect.x >= 120:
            currentLevel.scroll_x(0)

        if currentLevel.shift_x >= WIDTH *3 - 400:
            currentLevel.scroll_x(0)
            sprite_x_change = 0

        if player.rect.left <= 120 and player.sprite_x_change < 0:
            player.rect.x = 120
            player.rect.left = 120
            currentLevel.scroll_x(10)
        '''
        if player.rect.y <= 300:
            if player.standing == False and player.sprite_y_change < 0:
                currentLevel.scroll_y(10)

        if currentLevel.shift_y > 0:
            y_speed = -4
            if player.standing == True and player.rect.y < 300:
                y_speed = 4
            print(currentLevel.shift_y)
            currentLevel.scroll_y(y_speed)
        '''
        display.blit(background, backgroundRect)
        currentLevel.drawer(display)
        # Refresh screen
        player.updater(currentLevel.platforms)
        clock.tick(30)
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.quit()
        loop = False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Group` use `self.image` and `self.rect` to `blit` element so

1. create subsurface using [pygame.Surface.subsurface](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface) and `(x_sheet, y_sheet, height, length)` - and assign to `self.image`
2. assign `(x_screen, y_screen, height, length)` to `self.rect`

.

```
class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, display, x_screen, y_screen, x_sheet, y_sheet, height, length):
        super().__init__()

        self.tiles = pygame.image.load("tiles_spritesheet.png")

        self.image = self.tiles.subsurface(pygame.Rect(x_sheet, y_sheet, height, length))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(x=x_screen, y=y_screen)


        #display.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```